# Table View with Section for Date range

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following data displayed in Table View from

```
// declaration of Array
 NSMutableArray *listOfItems;

//Initialize the array.
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Adding Item to array
[listOfItems addObject:[object description]];

// Populating tableView with Array
NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Which shows :

- 2012-08-10 07:52:39 +0000

  2012-08-10 07:56:46 +0000

  2012-08-10 07:57:01 +0000

  2012-08-13 02:14:02 +0000

  2012-08-13 02:20:29 +0000

  2012-08-10 07:56:46 +0000

  2012-08-14 08:44:33 +0000

Now I need to have a segmented table view so that final result should be like this

- Header

  - 2012-08-10

  Values

  - 2012-08-10 07:52:39 +0000
  - 2012-08-10 07:56:46 +0000
  - 2012-08-10 07:57:01 +0000
  - 2012-08-10 07:56:46 +0000
- Header

  - 2012-08-13

  Values

  - 2012-08-13 02:14:02 +0000
  - 2012-08-13 02:20:29 +0000
  - Header 2012-08-14

  Values

  - 2012-08-14 08:44:33 +0000

ie Header for each day and different values of each day in each section
How can i do so ?

Comment: Just as a little help, without code: 
I would suggest that you create just 2 arrays for your list of items. Create a method which handles the seperation of your items into these arrays. It should create one array with your header dates and in the other array(a 2D) you are adding arrays with the values.
Then you will have your date in the right order to fill a tableview. I dont know how you want to display the difference between your header data and your values? Perhaps you can add some spaces for every cell which will contain your values to create the "collapse"-effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:[NSArray alloc]initWithObjets:@"2012-08-10 07:52:39 +0000",@"2012-08-10    07:56:46 +0000",@"2012-08-10 07:57:01 +0000",nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray alloc]initWithObjets:@"2012-08-13 02:14:02 +0000",@"2012-08-13 02:20:29 +0000",nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray alloc]initWithObjets:@"2012-08-14 08:44:33 +0000",nil]];
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return array.count;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewl numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *tempArray=[array objectAtIndex:section];
    return tempArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewl cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *tempArray=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.session]
    cell.textLabel.text=[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *tempArray=[array objectAtIndex:section];
    return [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```